# OutOfMemoryException loading images in androidTV using universal image loader library.

Tags: android

```
I am using below mentioned code:

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();     
        config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)   
        .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())    
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()    
        .threadPoolSize(1)
        .build();

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
         .cacheOnDisc(true)
         .resetViewBeforeLoading()
        //.cacheInMemory()
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
        .build();

        imageLoader.init(config);
```

here using given code i am displaying the image using ImageLoaderConfiguration method and display options.

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, logo_image, options,      
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                    FailReason failReason) {

            }

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                    Bitmap loadedImage) {

                // imgAppLogo.setBackground(new
                // BitmapDrawable(loadedImage));

            }
        });
```

Still in AndroidTv it is throwing exception(OutOfMemoryExcepotion)..

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Glide jar instaed of ImageLoader Library

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.github.bumptech.glide/glide/3.4.0

benifits of glide:
https://github.com/bumptech/glide